# Stop from changing new row format to Times New Roman

Tags: vba, excel

I have excel with two sheets with one table in each. From time to time some info from table in sheet1 needs to be moved to table sheet2 (lets call them ApplicationsTable and FinishedTable)

I have created button for that purpose. First you have to select entry row needed to be copied and after button click it creates new line in the bottom of FinishedTable and populates with info from AplicationsTable. Everything works fine except for some reason the new line created is formatted Times New Roman 11 pt. despite the fact that ApplicationsTable and rest of the FinishedTable are formatted Arial 10 pt.

I have tried copying and pasting format from one row above in FinishedTable, but I can't make it work for some reason. Can you give me some advice what road I should take to make new line retain original table formatting? My code:

```
Sub Move_info()

Dim shNr As Worksheet
Dim fList As ListObject
Dim nEntry As ListRow
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim xForm As Long
Dim pForm As Long

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Register")
Set shNr = Worksheets("Finished applications")
Set fList = shNr.ListObjects("FinishedTable")
With fList.Range
    lastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With

'stops macro if selected one than more row
If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

'if selected entry doesen't match criteria, stops from copying info
If Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Finished" Then
'line for adding new line at the bottom of the FinishedTable
    Set nEntry = fList.ListRows.Add
'Lines for moving info from ApplicationsTable to new row in FinishedTable

    With nEntry
        .Range(1) = shNr.Cells(lastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        .Range(2) = "=Register!T" & ActiveCell.Row
        .Range(4) = sh1.Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(6) = sh1.Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(7) = sh1.Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(10) = sh1.Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(11) = sh1.Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        End With
    'Up to this part code works as intended, line created, info is moved

    'with code below I tried to copy format from one row above last and paste it to last row 
    'I do not get any error, but format remains unchanged

    xForm = shNr.Cells(lastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Row
    Rows(xForm).Copy
    pForm = shNr.Cells(lastRow, "A").Row
    Rows(pForm).EntireRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'selects first cell which where user have to write info by hand, works as intended
    Application.GoTo shNr.Cells(lastRow, "C").Offset(1, 0)
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Could be that the default format of your Excel is Times New Roman?

Comment: Table is formatted to Arial 10 pt and everywhere I click is the same formatting, where I should change default format?

Comment: The default format is an option of Excel itself. But you could try something different. If you know where this table starts (let's say that your first data row is A2), probably you could do something like `Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Name="Arial"` and `Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Size=10`. That way, you would apply the wished format to all your table.

Comment: Tried your advice and added 'Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Name="Arial" Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Size=10' before application go. Worked like charm. The only one question left why I was getting Times New Roman despite the fact it is nowhere used. I have theory that it has something to do with 'nEntry = fList.ListRows.Add' , but my knowledge of VBA to weak to figure it out, so probably it is a question I will never now the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know where this table starts (let's say that your first data row is A2), probably you could do something like:

```
Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Name="Arial"
Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Size=10.
```

That way, you would apply the wished format to all your table.

About why you have it in Times New roman, could be because it is the default format of Excel. To check it out, check the options in Excel. My version is 2007 and in Spanish, but I'll ad a screenshoot of how I do it. Maybe it can help you out.

First, click on the Office/File button and second, click on the Excel Options button:

[image]

And afther that, find section called something like *Most frequent* or *Most used*, and there you should have the option for the default format.

[image]

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

With *Foxfire And Burns And Burns* advice I overcome problem by adding  `Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Name="Arial"` and `Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Size=10` to the end of the code. I still have no Idea why I was getting Times New Roman font, but maybe this will help someone with similar problem. Final code:

```
Sub Move_info()

Dim shNr As Worksheet
Dim fList As ListObject
Dim nEntry As ListRow
Dim lastRow As Long

Set sh1 = Worksheets("Register")
Set shNr = Worksheets("Finished applications")
Set fList = shNr.ListObjects("FinishedTable")
With fList.Range
    lastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
End With

If Selection.Rows.Count > 1 Then
    Exit Sub
End If

If Range("D" & (ActiveCell.Row)).Value = "Finished" Then
    Set nEntry = fList.ListRows.Add

    With nEntry
        .Range(1) = shNr.Cells(lastRow, "A").Offset(-1, 0).Value + 1
        .Range(2) = "=Register!T" & ActiveCell.Row
        .Range(4) = Range("C" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(6) = Range("I" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(7) = Range("H" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(10) = Range("P" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        .Range(11) = Range("Q" & ActiveCell.Row).Value
        End With

   Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Name="Arial"
   Range("A2").CurrentRegion.Font.Size=10

    Application.GoTo shNr.Cells(lastRow, "C").Offset(1, 0)
End If

End Sub
```